# Разделить List<> на две части C#(mvc)

Tags: c#, mvc

Всем доброго времени суток, есть метод который читает данные из файла и заполняет List. В списке всегда будет фиксированное число данных = 8. Мне нужно разбить Count поровну, одну часть в одну таблицу другую часть в другую. Сейчас пока додумался только так разделить:

```
@{
  int i = 0;
 }

 @foreach (var b in ViewBag.ReadBin)
 {
  if (i <= 3)
   {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>@b.NumberPosition</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.ShaftNumberLower</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.ShaftNumberUpper</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.DiameterShaftLower</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.DiameterShaftUpper</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
      i++;
   }

   else
   {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>@b.NumberPosition</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.ShaftNumberLower</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>@b.ShaftNumberUpper</p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
 }
```

Контроллер:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 readonly ReadBinaryFile _readBinary = new ReadBinaryFile();
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   var transhipments = _readBinary.ReadBin();
   ViewBag.ReadBin = transhipments;
   return View();
  }
 }
```

Но это не совсем то что мне нужно, все в одной таблице, а нужно раскидать в две. Как это сделать правильно? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
//сдесь пишешь заголовок таблицы
for (int i=0; i < ViewBag.ReadBin.Count()/2; i++)
{
    //постить в одну таблицу
}
//закываешь таблицу

//сдесь пишешь заголовок второй таблицы
for (int i=ViewBag.ReadBin.Count()/2; i <= ViewBag.ReadBin.Count; i++)
{
    //постить во вторую таблицу
}
//закываешь таблицу
```

будет разделять тебе поровну все данные независимо от количества переданых данных.

Comment: немного не пойму как сделать вторую таблицу ведь, если явно объявлять её в else то она будет создаваться с каждым проходом цикла, или я не прав ? а если быть точнее не совсем понимаю как разделить на 2 таблицы одним циклом. Спасибо

Comment: проапдейтил.....

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Через 3 мин закрою тему. Пока нельзя

Comment: Разобрался спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно немного говнокод, но:

```
var t1 = ViewBag.ReadBin.GetRange(0, 4);
var t2 = ViewBag.ReadBin.GetRange(5, 4);
```

Если всегда 8 элементов.